# New Reputation Graph Doesn't Work in IE9

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-graph, internet-explorer-9

The new graph is broken on a clean machine with the IE9 RTM installed (9.0.8112.16421):

[image: Default IE 9 Behaviour]

Compare that with "Compatibility Mode IE 7" Enabled:

[image: Compatibility Mode Enabled]

I'm posting this as a new bug (compared with [Reputation Graph Doesn't Work in IE9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70930/reputation-graph-doesnt-work-in-ie-9)) as that was based on the old FLOT graphing library (and marked as fixed), and this seems to be an issue with the HighChart one.

Comment: Interestingly it works on the StackExchange reputation graph.

Comment: @Joey True, but they're using a different graph style there.

Comment: Yes, but the overlay looks very similar (and is also SVG).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was an issue with line height CSS interpretation in IE9 and has since been fixed.

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer as soon as I've got access to a machine with IE9 ;)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, kept forgetting to confirm it ;)