# Alignment issue in reputation graph on network profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-graph

When hovering over the reputation graph on my network profile, the tooltip shows all entries on top of each other instead of as a list (as it did yesterday).

[image: Alignment issues in reputation graph]

I use Internet Explorer 9 on Windows 7. I tried clearing the browser cache and reloading the page but to no avail. The issue did not show up in Firefox 10, but did in the preview version of Internet Explorer 10 and the mobile version of IE on Windows Phone 7.5.

Looks like there was a [similar issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85451/new-reputation-graph-doesnt-work-in-ie9) reported a year ago.

Comment: Repro under the same conditions as you.

Comment: It is for efficiency, I believe. The pixels, they matter. That said, this issue is paramount, and I admire your acumen. I almost caught this but my acuity just isn;t the same. I upvote,

Comment: Yes, efficiency. Cramming all the pixels on top of each other results in maximum efficiency. No one cares about readability anymore; if you have real acumen and acuity, you'll be able to read it easily while remaining efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was just fixed by upgrading [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com) from v2.1.4 to v2.2.0. Thanks for the report.